# Is it possible for black to win this?

Tags: problems

```
[FEN "5bbk/5p1p/3b1P1P/6PK/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

How does Black get out and is it possible for Black to win? And if so, what is the least amount of moves it takes Black to win?

It is Black to move

Comment: If it's black to move, quick Stockfish run gives a mate in 16 with Bb4 or Bf4.

Comment: @DialFrost Perhaps I can turn the question around. Why did you think this position was interesting?

Comment: Idk if its interesting, i only wanted to see how many moves black could take to mate white

Comment: To make a claim on other peoples attention you shoud be sure that it is interesting

Comment: Is this a Chess960 position?  (due to the Bishop on g8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the least number of moves for Black to win?

It probably means you want an answer from the engine. I ran Stockfish 14+ at depth 61. Here's the line in which Stockfish recommended finishing the game ASAP(btw, it was checkmate in 17. Could have been 16 but I don't want to run it till depth 99).

```
[FEN "5bbk/5p1p/3b1P1P/6PK/8/8/8/8 b - - 0 1"]

1... Bb8 2. Kh4 Bb4 3. Kg4 Bd2 4. Kf5 Bbf4 5. Kg4 Bxg5 6. Kg3 Bxh6 7. Kg2 Bhf4 8. Kh3 h6 9. Kg2 Bh7 10. Kh3 Bf5+ 11. Kg2 Be4+ 12. Kf1 h5 13. Kf2 h4 14. Ke2 h3 15. Kd1 h2 16. Ke2 h1=Q 17. Kf2 Qe1#
```

But if you wanted an answer from a human then let me give my thoughts.

I personally would have played Bb4-Bd2 and then bring out the other dark square bishop to Ba3-Bc1. Try to win the pawn on g5 and h6. Then maybe go for an f6 pawn. After that, it's easy to convert by queening one of the pawns.

> How does Black get out?

By bringing out their both dark-squared bishops on h6-c1 diagonal and winning white's pawns.

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy win (that it's a mate in 16 I almost can't believe - best Stockfish now has is #21, but it's still running). Black simply gangs up the two black-square bishops against g5 (B-a3-c1, B-b4-d2 or so) and busts the king's prison. After that it's just the usual BB mate (or queening a pawn). BTW, the position is impossible to reach in play since the Bg8 couldn't get behind the pawns.

Comment: Ye i wasnt planning on making this position reachable btw